Cannot set up visual studio compiler
There are several similar questions here, but in case they are outdated, still let me ask.
I did
Needs["CCompilerDriver`"]

and then
CreateExecutable[
 StringJoin["int main(){\n", "  printf(\"Hello world.\\n\");\n", 
  "}\n"], "hiworld", 
 "Compiler" -> 
  CCompilerDriver`VisualStudioCompiler`VisualStudioCompiler, 
 "CompilerInstallation" -> 
  "c:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Preview", 
 "CompilerName" -> Automatic, "ShellOutputFunction" -> Print]

The output is this:
During evaluation of In[2]:= 
C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\Mathematica\SystemFiles\LibraryResources\Windows-x86-64\Working-asusi-3132-17180-1>call "c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Preview\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" amd64 
**********************************************************************
** Visual Studio 2022 Developer Command Prompt v17.12.0-pre.1.0
** Copyright (c) 2022 Microsoft Corporation
**********************************************************************
The system cannot find the file specified.
[vcvarsall.bat] Environment initialized for: 'x64'
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.42.34226.3 for x64
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

hiworld.c
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.42.34226.3
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:hiworld.exe 
user32.lib 
kernel32.lib 
gdi32.lib 
"/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\13.3\SystemFiles\Links\MathLink\DeveloperKit\Windows-x86-64\CompilerAdditions" 
"/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\13.3\SystemFiles\Libraries\Windows-x86-64" 
/out:C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\Mathematica\SystemFiles\LibraryResources\Windows-x86-64\Working-asusi-3132-17180-1\hiworld.exe 
hiworld.obj 
LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'user32.lib'
During evaluation of In[2]:= CreateExecutable::cmperr: Compile error: LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'user32.lib'
Out[2]= $Failed

Indeed I checked that I don't have anywhere on my system files user32.lib, kernel32.lib or gdi32.lib, neither do I have user64.lib, kernel64.lib, gdi64.lib or user.lib, kernel.lib or gdi.lib.
What's wrong and how to fix it?

Sounds like you didn't select a Windows SDK as part Visual Studio's installation.

@ihojnicki Perfect answer! You nailed it down exactly. Could you please turn this into an answer?
